# How to give the same boundary to multiple draggable objects?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I wish to set a boundary for two rectangles in my SVG.

I found this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1557377

In the example the boundaries get worked out from the position of the object that is dragged. Every circle in the example can only move a certain distance from where it started. What I wish to do is to create one drag function and use it on multiple shapes. This drag function will stop the shapes from going out of a certain area.

For example: I have a rectangle on the left side of the screen and one on the right but I don't want any of them to be able to go off screen. I started working on this but figured out this worked with regards to the position of the object getting dragged. So this works for the left hand rectangle but the right hand rectangle can go offscreen to the right but only so far to the left

```
    .on("drag", function(d) {    
            g = this;
            translate = d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate;
            x = d3.event.dx + translate[0],
            y = d3.event.dy + translate[1];

            if(x<-10){x=-10}
            if(x>width-10){width-10}
            if(y<-10){y=-10}
            if(y>height-10){y=height-10}

            d3.select(g).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
```

My question is: how do I impose the same boundary on anything that is dragged? *i.e* I don't want it to go off screen. I have variables width and height which are screen width and screen height respectively